# Compatibility with automatic transmissions between MDMA and M4TA Honda CRV 98

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, 4wd, crv

I need to buy an automatic transmissions but only found MDMA automatic transmission for this reason I need to know the compatibility between MDMA and M4TA.
Honda CRV 98 4X4 and mi car use M4TA

Exist compatibility between MDMA and M4TA?